# How can I write an excel formula that will concatenate text cells, skip blanks, and add a "/" between results?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two excel files, one that pulls a specific business unit abbreviation text value if there is a numeric value associated with that business unit.  I am trying to write a formula that will concatenate all business unit abbreviations with "/" in between them, but return JUST the single abbreviation with NO "/" if only one business unit is relevant.

I.E= if there are two relevant business units that are pulled from the first file, lets say TWC and BWC.  I need a formula that will go through 6 columns, recognize the two business acronyms, and return the values separated by a "/", **"TWC/BWC"**.  I have successfully done this using the following formula:

**=IF(S38<>0,S38,"")&IF(S38="",T38,"/"&T38)&IF(T38="",U38,"/"&U38)&IF(U38="",V38,"/"&V38)&IF(V38="",W38,"/"&W38)&IF(W38="",X38,"/"&X38)**

**However**, because of the way my formula is written, if there is a **SINGLE** business unit acronym, and nothing to concatenate, it will return **"TWC/"** when I just want the TWC with no "/" separator.

I know this should be an easy fix, but apparently I am dumb.  Please help a dumb person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have OFFICE 365 updated then:

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,S38:X38)
```

IF not

```
=LEFT(IF(S38<>"",S38 & "/","") & IF(T38<>"",T38 & "/","") & IF(U38<>"",U38 & "/","") & IF(V38<>"",V38 & "/","") & IF(W38<>"",W38 & "/","") & IF(X38<>"",X38 & "/",""),LEN(IF(S38<>"",S38 & "/","") & IF(T38<>"",T38 & "/","") & IF(U38<>"",U38 & "/","") & IF(V38<>"",V38 & "/","") & IF(W38<>"",W38 & "/","") & IF(X38<>"",X38 & "/",""))-1)
```